# Can I change windows 7 license key? getting the 'could be a fraudulent copy' warning

Tags: windows-7, license-key

I have 2 computers which I installed the same license key too.  I have multiple licenses, so I wish to fix this situation.  I am getting those warnings on both my computers.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can't remove the message. You can only install ONE key on ONE machine at ONE time.

Answer (score 1):

You should really contact Microsoft about this. However there are some workaround methods available (I've never tried them but they may work. Or not.):

There is a change product key if you bring up Properties.

[image]

Not sure if its still available for you.

Or try these:

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/19404-Not-genuine-after-KB971033-update-Read-this!
(Well leave the loader/illegal stuff out, just use the steps to get back to the original state.)